# How does the author go from this step to the next in proving angular momentum commutation relation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, operator-theory, physics, mathematical-physics

How does the author go from the end of this step:

[image]

To the first step here:

[image]

This is from Griffiths, Introduction to Quantum Mechanics, 2nd Edition, pgs. 160-161. I don't understand how he is using the canonical commutation relations.

Answer (score 1):

The middle two terms in the bottom line of the top equation are $0$ as explained in the displayed paragraph below. That leaves computing
\begin{align}
[yp_z,zp_x]&=yp_zzp_x-zp_xyp_z\\
&=yp_xp_zz-yp_xzp_z\\
&=yp_x(p_zz-zp_z)\\
&=yp_x[p_z,z]
\end{align}
and similarly for the other term. Note that I am using the fact that $y$ and $p_x$ commute with each other and with both $p_z$ and $z$.

Comment: I see why, for example, $x$ and $p_x$ fail to commute, but how does that apply to the middle terms? The middle terms do not share a symbol anywhere in there.

Comment: The operators $x$, $y$ and $p_z$ all mutually commute, so $[xp_z,yp_z]=0$. Similarly for the other middle term. You understand why they commute, right?